# Can not center text on image hover

Tags: html, css, image, webkit, hover

I am setting up a new homepage for my website. It will have a 2x2 grid of four images that change size with the window and they'll all have a hover text. I was able to do everything so far but I got stuck at one point, which possibly have an easy answer that I can't find. When I hover over the image, I want to make the text centered, no matter what the size of the window is. But I can not find the proper way to do it. The methods I've tried either don't center it both vertically and horizontally or the text goes off center when I resize the window. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Here's my code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ilkergoksen/bk2Sd/)

**HTML**

```
<section id="photos">
    <a href="/portfolio/test1.shtml" class="darken"><img src="image1"><span>GALLERY ONE</span></a>
    <a href="/portfolio/test2.shtml" class="darken"><img src="image2"><span>GALLERY TWO</span></a>
    <a href="/portfolio/test3.shtml" class="darken"><img src="image3"><span>GALLERY THREE</span></a>
    <a href="/portfolio/test4.shtml" class="darken"><img src="image4"><span>GALLERT FOUR</span></a>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#photos {
/* Prevent vertical gaps */
line-height: 0;
margin-left:150px;

-webkit-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-gap:   0px;
-moz-column-count:    2;
-moz-column-gap:      0px;
column-count:         2;
column-gap:           0px;
}

#photos img {
/* Just in case there are inline attributes */
width: 100% !important;
height: auto !important;
}

a.darken {
display: inline-block;
background: black;
padding: 0;
position:relative;  
}

a.darken img {
display: block;

-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
     -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
        transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

a.darken:hover img {
opacity: 0.3;           
}

a.darken span{visibility:hidden; font-size:16px;}
a.darken:hover span{color:#fff; visibility:visible;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
     -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
        transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

Comment: Just a hint, with CSS, 0anything will always be 0. Remove px from 0px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wont work in older browsers, but you can use a combination of "translate" and absolute positioning to vertically and horizontally align the text. Just add the following:

```
a.darken span{
  visibility:hidden; 
  font-size:16px;

  /* new styles below: */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  line-height: 100%;
}
```

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/bk2Sd/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these styles to the `<span>`:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 35%;
```

You can play with these values until you get it where you want.  Here is a working [example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/xw25t/7/).

Answer (score 0):

Since your `a.darken` selector already has relative positioning enabled, you can enable absolute positioning on the `span` attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/EfrainReyes/bk2Sd/4/

```
a.darken span {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    visibility:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

I added `display: block` and full height and width so I could use `text-align: center` on the `a.darken` selector.

Answer (score 0):

I propose something little more generic.

Since the size of the images is not known we can center horizontally the text using the `text-align` property and then centre it vertically by using an absolutely positioned element with `top` set to 50%.

Code to add:

```
a.darken span {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0
  position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bk2Sd/5/